# Characters between two exact characters

Tags: c#, regex, string

Let me show you what I want to do...

For example, I have this as an input

```
......1.......1.................
```

and what I want to do is

```
.......1111111..................
```

So I want to fill the space between the two ones with ones...

Also this should be able to be done too:

```
......11.....1..................
........11111...................
```

So I want just the inside...

Any C# help you can give?

Comment: Is your input binary or any possible string?

Comment: what about ......1.......1.......1......... ?

Comment: I tried this... but this gives me only the dots for the first example.. if there are 2 consistent ones it fails.. 
string output = converted.Split(new char[] { '1', '1' })[1];

Comment: The input is string. and there should be only one space between.. you can't have another space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved much easier without requiring a regular expression: You just want to "invert" the area of the string delimited by the first and last occurrence of a "1".

Here's an example solution:

```
string input = "..........1............1...";
int start = input.IndexOf('1');
int end = input.LastIndexOf('1');

char[] content = input.ToCharArray();
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
{
    content[i] = content[i] == '1' ? '.' : '1'; //invert
}
string output = new string(content);
```

Comment: Thank you man :) Perfect! But one more thing... How about this one
`............11111......`
How would  this print only the dots, because there is no speace between?

Comment: correct. Also you can always try it out yourself ;-)

Comment: Excuse me, but I still didn't get it.. The input could be in this format
`............11111......`
or in this format
`..........1............1...`
And it should automaticly do the right thing...

Comment: And it does - can you give me an example where this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

a regex way:

with multiline mode:

```
pattern: (?>(?<=^\.*)|\G)1(?=1*(\.))|\G(?<!^)\.(?=\.*(1))
replacement: $1$2
```

example:

```
string pattern = @"(?>(?<=^\.*)|\G)1(?=1*(\.))|\G(?<!^)\.(?=\.*(1))";
string input = @"......1.......1.................
......11.....1..................
......11111111..................";
string replacement = "$1$2";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```