# How to fill gap between two characters with regex

Tags: regex, r

I have a data set like below. I would like to replace all dots between two 1's with 1's, as shown in the desired.result.  Can I do this with `regex` in base `R`?

I tried:

```
regexpr("^1\\.1$", my.data$my.string, perl = TRUE)
```

Here is a solution in c#

[Characters between two exact characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292076/characters-between-two-exact-characters)

Thank you for any suggestions.

```
my.data <- read.table(text='
     my.string                           state
     ................1...............1.    A
     ......1..........................1    A
     .............1.....2..............    B
     ......1.................1...2.....    B
     ....1....2........................    B
     1...2.............................    C
     ..........1....................1..    C
     .1............................1...    C
     .................1...........1....    C
     ........1....2....................    C
     ......1........................1..    C
     ....1....1...2....................    D
     ......1....................1......    D
     .................1...2............    D
', header = TRUE, na.strings = 'NA', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

desired.result <- read.table(text='
     my.string                           state
     ................11111111111111111.    A
     ......1111111111111111111111111111    A
     .............1.....2..............    B
     ......1111111111111111111...2.....    B
     ....1....2........................    B
     1...2.............................    C
     ..........1111111111111111111111..    C
     .111111111111111111111111111111...    C
     .................1111111111111....    C
     ........1....2....................    C
     ......11111111111111111111111111..    C
     ....111111...2....................    D
     ......1111111111111111111111......    D
     .................1...2............    D
', header = TRUE, na.strings = 'NA', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This was the pattern that would have given a more useful result with `regexpr`: `"1\\.*1"`. The `^` and `$` would only allow matches if the 1's were at both ends of the string (and the lack of a quantifier would only match a string with only 1 period.)

Comment: What is the expected result when four (or more) 1 are on the same line (i.e. `..1...1...1...1..`)? `..11111...11111..` or `..1111111111111..`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is an option using `gsub` with the `\G` feature and lookaround assertions.

```
> gsub('(?:1|\\G(?<!^))\\K\\.(?=\\.*1)', '1', my.data$my.string, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "................11111111111111111." "......1111111111111111111111111111"
# [3] ".............1.....2.............." "......1111111111111111111...2....."
# [5] "....1....2........................" "1...2............................."
# [7] "..........1111111111111111111111.." ".111111111111111111111111111111..."
# [9] ".................1111111111111...." "........1....2...................."
# [11] "......11111111111111111111111111.." "....111111...2...................."
# [13] "......1111111111111111111111......" ".................1...2............"
```

The `\G` feature is an anchor that can match at one of two positions; the start of the string position or the position at the end of the last match. Since it seems you want to avoid the dots at the start of the string position we use a lookaround assertion `\G(?<!^)` to exclude the start of the string.

The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

You can find an overall breakdown that explains the regular expression [**here**](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%28%3F%3A1%7C%5CG%28%3F%3C%21%5E%29%29%5CK%5C.%28%3F%3D%5C.*1%29&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode).

Comment: Extraordinary.  Thank you.  When you do have the time please consider posting a description of how this works.

Comment: This is one bad ass regex. @MarkMiller, see [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3A1%7C%5CG%28%3F%3C%21%5E%29%29%5CK%5C.%28%3F%3D.*%3F1%29)

Comment: OMG! an automated regex-explainer?!?

Comment: @MarkMiller Here is the tested [regex](https://regex101.com/r/pJ9dO3/1) in action.

Comment: @DavidArenburg that isn't interpreting `\K` correctly, right? `\K` resets the match starting point and throws out previous matches I think. Compare the explanation of `\G` and `\K`

Comment: You can improve the pattern like this: `(?:\G(?!^)|\.*1(?=\.+1))\K\.` (the lookahead is tested only once and the `\G` branch (the most successful) is at the first position. The `+` quantifier excludes consecutive `1` and `\.*` avoids to test the two branches for each characters before the opening `1`)

Comment: @hwnd You don't have to ask permission and I will not post an answer. The idea/approach is already here.

Answer (score 7):

Using `gsubfn`, the first argument is a regular expression which matches the 1's and the characters between the 1's and captures the latter.  The second argument is a function, expressed in formula notation, which uses `gsub` to replace each character in the captured string with 1:

```
library(gsubfn)
transform(my.data, my.string = gsubfn("1(.*)1", ~ gsub(".", 1, x), my.string))
```

If there can be multiple pairs of 1's in a string then use `"1(.*?)1"` as the regular expression instead.

**Visualization** The regular expression here is simple enough that it can be directly understood but here is a debuggex visualization anwyays:

```
1(.*)1
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Cg9n9UYzWqf0eg6v)

Comment: Thanks for adding this.  I had given `gsubfn()` a quick shot (using lookahead and lookbehind assertions),  but was stymied by its non-PCRE regex engine. I like how clean this makes the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option that uses a relatively simple regex and the standard combination of `gregexpr()`, `regmatches()`, and `regmatches<-()` to identify, extract, operate on, and then replace substrings matching that regex.

```
## Copy the character vector
x <- my.data$my.string
## Find sequences of "."s bracketed on either end by a "1"
m <- gregexpr("(?<=1)\\.+(?=1)", x, perl=TRUE)
## Standard template for operating on and replacing matched substrings
regmatches(x,m) <- sapply(regmatches(x,m), function(X) gsub(".", "1", X))

## Check that it worked
head(x)
# [1] "................11111111111111111." "......1111111111111111111111111111"
# [3] ".............1.....2.............." "......1111111111111111111...2....."
# [5] "....1....2........................" "1...2............................."
```